# How do I copy the binaries from the `python` NuGet package into my project's build output?

Tags: python, c#, msbuild, nuget

Nothing happens when I reference [the `python` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/python) in my .csproj. I would like its binaries to be copied into my build directory. What do I need to change about my .csproj for that to happen?

My .csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="python" Version="3.11.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

That package has this `python.props` file located in /build/native:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Platform) == 'X64'">
    <PythonHome Condition="$(PythonHome) == ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath("$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\tools"))</PythonHome>
    <PythonInclude>$(PythonHome)\include</PythonInclude>
    <PythonLibs>$(PythonHome)\libs</PythonLibs>
    <PythonTag>3.11</PythonTag>
    <PythonVersion>3.11.2</PythonVersion>

    <IncludePythonExe Condition="$(IncludePythonExe) == ''">true</IncludePythonExe>
    <IncludeDistutils Condition="$(IncludeDistutils) == ''">false</IncludeDistutils>
    <IncludeLib2To3 Condition="$(IncludeLib2To3) == ''">false</IncludeLib2To3>
    <IncludeVEnv Condition="$(IncludeVEnv) == ''">false</IncludeVEnv>

    <GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn>_GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn311_None;$(GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn)</GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="$(Platform) == 'X64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PythonInclude);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(PythonLibs);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>

  <Target Name="GetPythonRuntimeFiles" Returns="@(PythonRuntime)" DependsOnTargets="$(GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn)" />

  <Target Name="_GetPythonRuntimeFilesDependsOn311_None" Returns="@(PythonRuntime)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_PythonRuntimeExe Include="$(PythonHome)\python*.dll" />
      <_PythonRuntimeExe Include="$(PythonHome)\python*.exe" Condition="$(IncludePythonExe) == 'true'" />
      <_PythonRuntimeExe>
        <Link>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      </_PythonRuntimeExe>
      <_PythonRuntimeDlls Include="$(PythonHome)\DLLs\*.pyd" />
      <_PythonRuntimeDlls Include="$(PythonHome)\DLLs\*.dll" />
      <_PythonRuntimeDlls>
        <Link>DLLs\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      </_PythonRuntimeDlls>
      <_PythonRuntimeLib Include="$(PythonHome)\Lib\**\*" Exclude="$(PythonHome)\Lib\**\*.pyc;$(PythonHome)\Lib\site-packages\**\*" />
      <_PythonRuntimeLib Remove="$(PythonHome)\Lib\distutils\**\*" Condition="$(IncludeDistutils) != 'true'" />
      <_PythonRuntimeLib Remove="$(PythonHome)\Lib\lib2to3\**\*" Condition="$(IncludeLib2To3) != 'true'" />
      <_PythonRuntimeLib Remove="$(PythonHome)\Lib\ensurepip\**\*" Condition="$(IncludeVEnv) != 'true'" />
      <_PythonRuntimeLib Remove="$(PythonHome)\Lib\venv\**\*" Condition="$(IncludeVEnv) != 'true'" />
      <_PythonRuntimeLib>
        <Link>Lib\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      </_PythonRuntimeLib>
      <PythonRuntime Include="@(_PythonRuntimeExe);@(_PythonRuntimeDlls);@(_PythonRuntimeLib)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Importance="low" Text="Collected Python runtime from $(PythonHome):%0D%0A@(PythonRuntime->'  %(Link)','%0D%0A')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Here is Python's documentation on this NuGet package:
https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-nuget-org-packages

They recommend calling `nuget.exe` directly like this:

```
nuget.exe install python -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory .
```

I would like the equivalent of that to happen when my project is built, except for the output to be my project's output directory.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(Pkgpython)\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This will copy all the contents of the `python` package into your build output directory.

To only copy the "tools" folder then you can instead do something like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(Pkgpython)\tools\**\*" Link="tools\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```